# Hola, tengo que dar acceso al evento a las personas que cumplan ciertas condiciones

Tags: javascript, queue

tengo que dar acceso al evento a las personas que cumplan ciertas condiciones y se me dificulta al momento de eliminar a las que tiene un numero de ticket repetido.

A partir de una Queue que va a recibir como parámetro que tiene en cada posición un objeto.
La idea es ir verificando uno a uno si la primer persona de la cola tiene los requisitos necesarios para ingresar al evento correspondiente (también recibido por parámetro). Los requisitos que debe cumplir son:

- Ser mayor de 18 años (18 inclusive es válido)
- Tener un ticket que corresponda con el evento (prop event de ticket)
- Que no haya ingresado ya otra persona al evento con ese mismo número de ticket
  Finalmente la función debe devolver un arreglo con todos los nombres de las personas que pudieron ingresar

Importante!: Aquellas personas que no cumplan con los requisitos para ingresar deben ser removidos de la cola

```
let personas = [
  {
     fullname: "Franco Etcheverri",
     age: 26,
     ticket: {
     number: 1,
     event: "Tomorrowland"
   }
   },
    {
     fullname: "Ariel Gentile",
     age: 19,
     ticket: {
     number: 2,
     event: "Tomorrowland"
    }
   },
  {
     fullname: "Javier Perea",
     age: 19,
     ticket: {
     number: 2,
     event: "Tomorrowland"
    }
   },
    {
     fullname: "Federico Pato",
     age: 24,
     ticket: {
     number: 3,
     event: "Tomo"
   },
      
 }]
  

var controlAcces = function(personas, event){
    // Tu código aca:
   let aux = []
   let auxDos = []
   
   personas.forEach((element) => {
     if(element.age >= 18 && element.ticket.event === event) {
        aux.push(element)
      }
   });
  

   return aux
  };
```

Comment: Lo que importa es que no se use dos veces el mismo numero de tickets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias agregar una variable para guardar el `number` de cada **ticket**, para posteriormente comparar si ya paso una persona con el mismo ticket.

```js
let personas = [{
    fullname: 'Franco Etcheverri',
    age: 26,
    ticket: {
      number: 1,
      event: 'Tomorrowland',
    },
  },
  {
    fullname: 'Ariel Gentile',
    age: 19,
    ticket: {
      number: 2,
      event: 'Tomorrowland',
    },
  },
  {
    fullname: 'Javier Perea',
    age: 19,
    ticket: {
      number: 2,
      event: 'Tomorrowland',
    },
  },
  {
    fullname: 'Federico Pato',
    age: 24,
    ticket: {
      number: 3,
      event: 'Tomo',
    },
  },
];

const controlAcces = (personas, event) => {
  let tickets = [];
  return personas.filter((persona) => {
    if (persona.age >= 18 && persona.ticket.event === event && !tickets.includes(persona.ticket.number)) {
      tickets.push(persona.ticket.number);
      return persona;
    }
  });
};

console.log(controlAcces(personas, 'Tomorrowland'));
```

Comment: Gracias broo !!